# Generate Unordered list for asp:menu in ASP.NET 3.5

Tags: asp.net-3.5

The asp:menu that I am using is rendering an old table layout.  Can someone help me create an unordered list with a nested unordered list for the hover menu.  I need the output to render like this:

```
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Link</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href=""></a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

XML Data feed looks like this:

```
<SiteMap>
        <item Text="(!menu.Home!)" NavigateUrl="default.aspx" LookId="VertTopItemLook"/>
        <item Text="(!menu.Categories!)" LookId="VertTopItemLook" />
        <item Text="(!menu.Sections!)" LookId="VertTopItemLook" />
        <item Text="(!menu.Manufacturers!)" LookId="VertTopItemLook" />
        <item Text="(!menu.CustomerService!)" NavigateUrl="t-service.aspx" LookId="VertTopItemLook">
                <MenuItem Text="(!menu.YourAccount!)" NavigateUrl="account.aspx" />
                <MenuItem Text="(!menu.OrderHistory!)" NavigateUrl="account.aspx" />
                <MenuItem Text="(!menu.FAQs!)" NavigateUrl="t-faq.aspx" />
                <MenuItem Text="(!menu.PolicyReturns!)" NavigateUrl="t-returns.aspx" />
                <MenuItem Text="(!menu.Shipping!)" NavigateUrl="t-shipping.aspx" />
                <MenuItem Text="(!menu.Contact!)" NavigateUrl="t-contact.aspx" />
                <MenuItem Text="(!menu.PolicyPrivacy!)" NavigateUrl="t-privacy.aspx" />
                <MenuItem Text="(!menu.PolicySecurity!)" NavigateUrl="t-security.aspx" />
        </item>
</SiteMap>
```

Comment: the data is coming from an XML file